# Why are filters in an excel sheet showing unmatched rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I've an excel sheet with around 1000+ rows. I've applied filter on the first column with value "*GS1 - Indian History*". It is just supposed to show 16 rows, but it is showing rows containing other values (including blanks) for this column.

I've tried clearing formatting & reformatting entire column. I've changed the format of the cell contents from "General" to "Text". Still it isn't working.

[image]

Why on the earth is this happening? And how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I just found something else fishy:

[image]
There are lot more records than 512. Any by any chance is this 512 any limit imposed? (as 512 fits in the series of 512, 1024, 2048 etc)

[You can download file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05HI8_2Zj9KV0dBTEY4U2Qwelk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: May I take a look at this file in order to help you with this issue? Please erase all non-related data, share it and provide us with a link. What software and what version are you using?

Comment: @Mike: I've added the link at the end. Check it out.

Comment: Why would any one want to close this question? What guidelines is it not meeting? Day be day Superuser is becoming more restrictive!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue caused by blank (empty) cells at the column you are filtering. The actual problem occurred upon filter creation, while you made filter when you had first cell selected instead of whole column.

**How to fix it:**

- Click at the first cell and press Filter again to delete current filter;
- Then click at the first column and press Filter to create a new one.

[image]

Now it will works like a charm. :)

Comment: @claws You are highly welcome!

Comment: It works for me as well. But I didn't understand the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you had mentioned when you were having trouble with the filter in excel, when you were trying to filter just "GS1 - Indian History".

I was able to fix the problem in my case. It turns out I had somehow converted the spreadsheet to a table, whatever that means.  But I had done it while I was still making the spreadsheet.  I later added more rows, and those weren't being included in the filter.

I somehow came across the option to "convert table to range" while one of the earlier cells was highlighted.  That did the trick; the filter started working as intended, even with blank cells.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on any cell within the blue range -> Table -> Convert to Range -> Yes

[Convert an Excel table to a range of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKxN8.png)

This way, the typical characteristic of the table was restored, as well as filtering within the whole table or single column only.

Source:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-an-excel-table-to-a-range-of-data-0b326ff1-1764-4ebe-84ea-786265d41c77
- https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/669007-blue-border-round-data.html

Comment: I've dowvoted you for 2 reasons: 1. This question is 5 years old, with an upvoted answer that's been accepted. Your time would be better spent on recently asked questions without good solutions. 2. Your solution won't solve the issue - in the accepted answer you'll see the problem is blank cells/rows that break up the data, which prevents the "Filter" button from finding all the data. These blank cells will prevent Convert to Table from working properly, so you'll have the same problem (albeit with a bit more visibility into where excel thinks the data is).

Comment: Based on the screenshots attached by the author and his posts, blank cells might not be the only problem that he encounters. 
I'd prefer knowing his opinion, whether the instructions of the most upvoted answer helped him.
Apart from that, I wasn't able to find the right thread related to the group of problems caused by filtering in Excel and the date of creation doesn't tell much in this case. The only relevant thread on Microsoft forum is closed: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-filter-not-working-extra-rows-appearing/b770ada0-5f8d-4ca1-85ea-d631cce66ac3?page=2